# Responsive hamburger menu using ul/li tags

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-lists, hamburger-menu

I've been trying to follow a few tutorials to turn a horizontal menubar into a drop-down hamburger menu when displayed on smaller screens, but I'm struggling to make it come together properly. I noticed a lot of tutorials seem to do away with ul/li format, which I'd like to save for semantic and accessible reasons, but this has left me struggling to get the dropdown to appear correctly on the screen.

My goal is to allow the hamburger menu to open the four menu items, centered on the screen, below the top header bar. I've managed to make the hamburger menu "work," but it's opening the items not centered and not below the top menubar. Any suggestions that don't require revamping the entire menubar code, if possible?

```js
const menu = document.querySelector(".nav");
let open;

function openMenu() {
  if (open) {
    menu.style.display = "none";
    open = false;
  } else if (!open) {
    menu.style.display = "block";
    open = true;
  }
}
```

```css
.menubar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f5f5f5;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-user-select: all;
  user-select: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 24px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 15px;
  position: absolute;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 18px;
  flex-direction: row;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav li {
  margin: 0 15px;
}

.hamburger {
  margin: 0 13px 0 auto;
  height: inherit;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 801px) {
  .nav {
    display: flex !important;
  }
  .hamburger {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .hamburger {
    display: flex;
  }
  .nav {
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="menubar">
    <a href="" class="logo">WEBSITE NAME</a>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
      <li><a href="">MENU1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">MENU2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">ABOUT</a></li>
    </ul>

    <input type="image" class="hamburger" onclick={openMenu()} src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b2/Hamburger_icon.svg/800px-Hamburger_icon.svg.png" />
  </div>
</body>
```

Accompanying [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jesseoffy/8z147s3L/70/).

Answer (score 0):

You can add a window load and resizing listener. When the window gets smaller than 800px the script will add a class to your element.

I currently have it set to place a class `.mobile`. Made the necessary stylistic changes to this class for the mobile menu

Add this in your JS code:

```js
    window.addEventListener('resize', setMobileClass);
    window.addEventListener('load', setMobileClass);

    function setMobileClass() {
        if (window.innerWidth <= 800) {
            menu.classList.add('mobile');
        } else {
            menu.classList.remove('mobile');
        }
    };
```

Add this in your CSS:

```css
    .mobile {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0px;
        top: 50px;
    }
```

**EXAMPLE:**

```js
const menu = document.querySelector(".nav");
let open;

function openMenu() {
    if (open) {
        menu.style.display = "none";
        open = false;
    } else if (!open) {
        menu.style.display = "block";
        open = true;
    }
}

window.addEventListener('resize', setMobileClass);
window.addEventListener('load', setMobileClass);

function setMobileClass() {
    if (window.innerWidth <= 800) {
        menu.classList.add('mobile');
    } else {
        menu.classList.remove('mobile');
    }
};
```

```css
.menubar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f5f5f5;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    -webkit-user-select: all;
    user-select: none;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.logo {
    font-size: 24px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding-left: 15px;
    position: absolute;
}

.nav {
    display: flex;
    font-size: 18px;
    flex-direction: row;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

.nav li {
    margin: 0 15px;
}


.hamburger {
    margin: 0 13px 0 auto;
    height: inherit;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 801px) {
    .nav {
        display: flex !important;
    }

    .hamburger {
        display: none;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .hamburger {
        display: flex;
    }

    .nav {
        display: none;
        text-align: center;
    }
}

.mobile {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menubar">
    <a href="" class="logo">WEBSITE NAME</a>
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="">MENU1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">MENU2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">ABOUT</a></li>
    </ul>

    <input type="image" class="hamburger" onclick={openMenu()}
        src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b2/Hamburger_icon.svg/800px-Hamburger_icon.svg.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: Is this any different than just adding the CSS code in your .mobile class into the .nav class I have under the max-width: 800 section of my code? I fiddled around with it based on your reply, and it seems that simply adding: { position: absolute; right: 0px; top: 50px; width: 100%; } to my media-screen's .nav tag does the trick.

Comment: Of course, you can only do it with CSS but... When we write code, the main idea, apart from working, is to be easy to read and edit. For something as simple as what you want to achieve, you have too much CSS code. My recommendation is to significantly reduce the CSS code by using the fact that you can add and remove a class

Answer (score 0):

I found a fitting and elegant solution based on 54ka's answer. Instead of adding a mobile class with extra JS code, I modified screen-size restricted nav class to be the following:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .hamburger {
    display: flex;
  }
  .nav {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    right: 0px;
    top: 50px;
  }
}
```

This ensured that the menu would appear centered, underneath the menubar. Additional background-color and border commands can be added to clean up the dropdown menu.